# Old Version glsl in modern graphics cards

Tags: opengl, glsl

This is a classic example of glsl version 1.2

```
// VERTEX SHADER
void main(){
  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}

//FRAGMENT SHADER
void main(){
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.4,0.4,0.8,1.0);
}
```

My question is if I have a modern graphics card with glsl version 3.0 or 4.0 Can I continue using the vertex shader and fragment shader from version 1.2 or am I forced to use the new version.

This question I do it because I understand that the core OpenGL version 4.0 also contains all previous versions. I do not know if this also applies to the GLSL language.

Thank you.

Comment: That's what the [GLSL `#version` directive](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Version), is there for!

Comment: Yes, you can continue to do this with `#version 400 compatibility`. The default profile in 1.50+ is `core`, but if you use `compatibility` all that nasty deprecated stuff will still be available to you. Assuming your implementation supports them.

Comment: Very Well my friend. Thank you very much! :-)